# javascript - Merge 2 objects in Array of Objects into one Object

Tags: javascript

It is possible to merge this array of objects in javascript
or maybe some other way to merge this data?

cause i will use it in frontend (Vue.js)

```
[
  {
    "aset": "aset",
    "keterangan": "(form kc 0200 kode pos 130)",
    "jumlah": "0",
    "side": "left",
    "bagian": "2"
  },
  {
    "aset": "aset",
    "keterangan": "penjumlahan Kolom Jumlah sub KC0200 kode pos 131~160",
    "jumlah": "0",
    "side": "right",
    "bagian": "2"
  },
  {
    "aset": "aset",
    "keterangan": "Pembiayaan Bagi Hasil (form kc 0200 kode pos 170)",
    "jumlah": "0",
    "side": "left",
    "bagian": "2"
  },
  {
    "aset": "aset",
    "keterangan": "penjumlahan Kolom Jumlah sub KC0200 kode pos 171~173",
    "jumlah": "0",
    "side": "right",
    "bagian": "2"
  },
]
```

into something like

```
[
  {
    "aset": "aset",
    "keterangan": "(form kc 0200 kode pos 130)",
    "jumlah": "0",
    "keterangan2": "penjumlahan Kolom Jumlah sub KC0200 kode pos 131~160",
    "jumlah2": "0",
    "bagian": "2"
  },
  {
    "aset": "aset",
    "keterangan": "Pembiayaan Bagi Hasil (form kc 0200 kode pos 170)",
    "jumlah": "0",
    "keterangan": "penjumlahan Kolom Jumlah sub KC0200 kode pos 171~173",
    "jumlah": "0",
    "bagian": "2"
  },
]
```

So i want create object where is merge "left" and "right" side

thanks before

Comment: Where is "side": "right" in your result?

Comment: what are the requirements? `side` left should be merged with right and put a `2` if fields are duplicated? The fact you use this data in front end, vue, or anywhere else, manes nothing, as data is JSON, hence universally usable.

Comment: i want to remove "side" prop because don't need it anymore @MaulikSakhida

Comment: Ah, my bad
if the "side" is "left" then create new object
if the "side" is "right" then assign it into "left" object
@AndreaGiammarchi

Comment: you can use delete keyword to delete properties

Comment: the problem is merge 2 object with left and right side into one object

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code

Comment: *So i want create object where is merge "left" and "right" side* ... merging usually means grouping, as array, same properties, here you have a `prop` and a sudden `prop2`, instead of an array, or `prop1` or ... so, again, what are the requirements?

Comment: so, i want to merge object with "side":"left" and "side":"right" into one object

Comment: ```let resp = []
        rows[0].map(e => {
          let o = {}
          if (e.side == 'left') {
            Object.assign(o, ...e)
          }else{
            Object.assign(o, ...e)
          }
          resp.push(o)
        })```

tried code above but not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```js
let arr1=[
  {
    "aset": "aset",
    "keterangan": "(form kc 0200 kode pos 130)",
    "jumlah": "0",
    "side": "left",
    "bagian": "2"
  }
]
let arr2=[{
"jumlah2":"0",
"keterangan2":"penjumlahan Kolom Jumlah sub KC0200 kode pos 131~160"

}]


for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
delete arr1[i]["side"]
arr1[i]={...arr1[i],...arr2[i]}
}

console.log(arr1)
```